How to pass a function argument of type Dataframe to a SparkSQL query
I have a spark.sql query that is wrapped inside a function. I want to pass the query a function argument that is a dataframe but getting some error. Can anyone see if I am doing something wrong?
Function:
1  def my_function(df_table: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
2 
3    sql_query = f"""
4    SELECT DISTINCT dt.CountryId,
5    Cast(RIGHT(dt.RegionIdentifier, 2) as Integer) as RegionID
6    FROM {df_table} dt 
7    WHERE dt.CountryCode = 23
8    """
9
10   df = spark.sql(sql_query)
11   return df

and this is how I call it in a notebook:
df_table = spark.table('path_to_table/_location/')
my_function(df_table)

Error message I get:
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '['. SQLSTATE: 42601

If i remove the {df_table} on LINE-6, and put the name of table hardcoded, it works. Is there a way to pass in the table name as Dataframe and have it passed as an arg?
and when I print the sql_query, it shows:
SELECT DISTINCT dt.CountryId,
Cast(RIGHT(dt.RegionIdentifier, 2) as Integer) as RegionID
FROM DataFrame[CountryId: bigint, RegionID: int, RegionIdentifier: string, TimeOf: timestamp] dt
WHERE dt.CountryCode = 23


To be able to access the DataFrame within a SQL query, register it as a temporary view using method DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView:
def my_function(df_table: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    temp_view_name = "some_temp_view"
    df_table.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_view_name)

    sql_query = f"""
    SELECT DISTINCT dt.CountryId,
    Cast(RIGHT(dt.RegionIdentifier, 2) as Integer) as RegionID
    FROM {temp_view_name} dt 
    WHERE dt.CountryCode = 23
    """

    df = spark.sql(sql_query)
    return df


Your SQL statement expects a name of the table - you can't put DataFrame object instead, they are not equivalent. DataFrame does not necessary have a name, since it can be result of some operations on DataFrame that you loaded.
If you expect that this function always accepts a table as an argument, then just pass the name (string).
If you expect that sometimes it may get a DataFrame that is a result of some other actions, than you can't build your select as an SQL statement but you can add it by applying pyspark functions, like that
 import pyspark.sql.functions as F

 df = df_table.where(F.col("CountryCode") == 23).\
               select(F.countDistinct(F.col("CountryId")), 
                      F.right(F.col("RegionIdentifier"),2).\
                                cast("integer").alias("RegionID"))

